# Qvalue.R results

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

I have some p-values that I want to convert to q-values.  The issue I am running into is that the qvalues being generated by storey's qvalue package are all in a very tight range (i.e. .25-.35).

I am not sure what this means.  I am working with a ridiculously small dataset, given the number of hypotheses, could that be the problem?  I could understand if I had all high q-values, but that all of them having a ~.25 q-value... I'm just lost.

I would really appreciate it if someone could explain what I am not understanding here about q-values.

Thanks.

Edit:

A histogram of the p-values

[image]

Descriptive Statistics

- count    249.000000
- mean       0.395376
- std        0.263631
- min        0.006288
- 25%        0.173421
- 50%        0.351731
- 75%        0.588190
- max        1.000000

Dispersion

- p-val < .2  0.026
- p-val > .2  0.092

Comment: First off, do you understand how a q-value is calculated from a p-value? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate#q-value

Comment: I have read the Storey paper, I even implemented it myself to get a better understanding of what was going on.  My real problem is I have not used it enough to get an intuition for the behaviour of qvalues under different conditions.  I was hoping to get a qualitative description of q-values and their relationship to different p-value distributions.

Answer (score 1):

As Storey's q-values are estimates of the pFDR, with the Bayesian interpretation of "the probability of the null given the data", my guess is that the estimated  alternative distribution has high variance so that almost all values away from the null have similar pFDR.

Are your pvalues very spread except for a concentration near 0?

Comment: I appreciate your response.  I have added a histogram of the p-values and some descriptive statistics, including the dispersion for p-vals < and > .2.  They are concentrated near zero.  They were generated via permutation testing.  In general, I would expect this to be true. The method I am characterizing basically asks the question, can I differentiate between two subtypes with this network, where there are 249 networks.